# Unauthorized: master key is required (Code: 0, Version: 1.12.0) + iOS + Parse + SNS after Parse Migration to AWS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, parse-platform, parse-error

When I sending push notification from iOS App after parse migration into AWS + MongoLab, I get an error - unauthorized: master key is required (Code: 0, Version: 1.12.0), how I resolve it, and I using iOS parse code for sending message for notification and AWS SNS service by using Mobile Hub.

before parse migration to AWS, push notification send perfectly, after migration parse push to aws using this link https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3NE69QDHI7LJK/Migrating-from-Parse-Push-to-Amazon-SNS, I am getting this error - unauthorized: master key is required (Code: 0, Version: 1.12.0) even I had also used one signal instead of SNS for removing this error, still I am getting the same error, it works fine when I test notification using step -4 of the above link.  below is my iOS parse code which I am using in the app -

PFQuery *queryInstallation = [PFInstallation query];
                 [queryInstallation whereKey:kESInstallationUserKey matchesQuery:query];

```
             PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
             [push setQuery:queryInstallation];
             NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   message, @"alert",
                                   @"Increment", @"badge",
                                   @"homerun.caf", @"sound",
                                   @"m", @"p",
                                   nil];
             [push setData:data];
             [push sendPushInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error)
              {
                  if (error != nil)
                  {
                      NSLog(@"SendPushNotification send error.");
                  }
              }];
```

I am using client side code mainly, but for some aspect also using cloud side code.

Comment: no code shown in your question. point to appropriate docs link and are you pushing from cloud side or client side ?

Comment: Komal - I believe your problem is with sending push notifications from the client. As stated in the parse-serever Push wiki.. "Client push is not supported. You can only use masterKey to send push notifications." For sending from server, use only the Master Key. More here: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Push

Comment: I have followed this link- http://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Push, and use master key also in server code, still I am getting this error, is there any way to include master key using iOS or Parse code in Front-End

Comment: Hi Dennis - please solve my problem, now I am sending push notification only by cloud side as Client push is not supported, still I have not received any push notification and any error from server while SNS is creating the Application & token for registering the device token using MobileHub downloaded code for iOS (but it is not interacting with cloud code).